# Date from negative float

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp in a variable

```
$data = (float) -2208988800;
```

Is it possible to create correct date from this data?
`date("d.M.Y", $data)` returns "07.02.2036"

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: timestamp CAN be negative on x64 machines. Negative numbers are used for dates before 1.1.1970....

Comment: @Glavić That's an excellent point, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Glavic, you have to be on x64 to calculate a date before the epoch?

Comment: Passing it as a float will use microtime I believe in PHP

Comment: @CharlieS: no. `date()` on x86 can also take negative timestamp as 2nd parameter. You just cannot use bigger integers as `PHP_INT_MAX`, which in this case is.

Comment: Negative integers are not floating point numbers. Did you mean to refer to float in title and question?

Comment: "5.1.0  The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows)." -- so negative integers are fine, and floats don't work, positive or negative. The sign has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You are using the wrong type. PHP's `date()` function requires an integer here, not a float. Passing wrong types into a function should not make you expect it to work because you're not using it as announced.

Comment: @hakre, @Anthony: function `date()` accepts 2nd parameter integer or float, [example](http://3v4l.org/VBXIg); that is not the problem.

Comment: @Glavić: Well, your example doesn't proof a thing as PHP is loosely typed. Therefore you need to relate to the PHP manual in which it's written that the parameter *is* integer. You can also pass a string in there, try it, however, the expected type is integer. Therefore you need to deal with the case that type juggling is in action: http://www.php.net/language.types.type-juggling - And the string example: http://3v4l.org/9XTbn (you don't need to cast to float btw., having a dot in that number does that already).

Comment: But don't take my comment too seriously, it's also not the integer limit, it looks like that PHP's `date()` adheres to the **NTP limit**, which is at *06:28:16 UTC on 7 Feb 2036* (which is also not 32bit integer limit, but related)

Comment: *Hint:* In case you experience some weird dates with PHP's date, checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time if you can spot it.

Comment: @hakre: I totally agree with you but I was just saying that passing as float isn't the main problem here; we can also pass as integer and the problem would be the same. Like you said, when float `-2208988800` is casted to int it becomes `2085978496`, thats why `date()` returns year 2036.

Comment: @Glavić: See my other comment, it's not 2147483647 (INT_MAX) but 2085978496, I assume due to the same reason NTP has. But I do not specifically know that, it's just by the date I found on Wikipedia. You're probably motivated to dissect this a little more :)

Comment: @hakre: I still think the problem is 32bit machine, because 32bit machines have range from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`; and `-2208988800` is out of this range. I just don't know why and how does PHP convert (when casting) number `-2208988800` to `2085978496`?

Comment: @Glavić: I don't know ^^ Perhaps worth a question for Stackoverflow? ;) Perhaps it rolls-over multiple times before it stands.

Comment: @hakre: I think you are basically correct, overflow is rolled over, until it is in integer range. But this is probably [undefined behavior](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/10/09/Overflow-float-integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get result `07.02.2036` because you are on x86 (32-bit machine), where integer range is from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` (see `echo PHP_INT_MAX;`). PHP internally cast's 2nd parameter of `date()` function to integer, so on 32-bit machine, string or float `-2208988800` will become integer `2085978496`, which is date 2036-02-07, [demo](https://eval.in/82922).

```php
echo date('Y-m-d', -2208988800);
# 2036-02-07 (x86)
# 1900-01-01 (x64)
```

<kbd>[**run code on x86 machine**](https://eval.in/82889)</kbd>

<kbd>[**run code on x64 machine**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/cda-tnh)</kbd>

If you wish to use negative timestamps on both machines, x86 and x64, use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) extension:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('@-2208988800');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/82890)</kbd>

Note that, for dates before the unix epoch, method `getTimestamp()` will return `false`, where method `format('U')` will return a correct timestamp number.

```php
var_dump( $dt->format('U') );    # -2208988800
var_dump( $dt->getTimestamp() ); # false
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/82926)</kbd>